# Ory Hydra - In PKCE flow where is code_verifier stored and checked?

Tags: oauth-2.0, pkce, hydra

I am using Ory Hydra to complete an OAuth2 `authorization_code` flow with PKCE.  Something is wrong with my setup.  The code verifier is not actually validated.  I am able to exchange the authz code for a token whether I provide the right verifier, an invalid one or even not provide one at all.

I am looking through the Hydra source code but having a hard time finding:

1. Where is the code that adds the session to the PKCE table? This is probably called by [the `oauth2/auth` endpoint](https://github.com/ory/hydra/blob/master/oauth2/handler.go#L674).
2. Where is the code that validates the code_verifier? I assume it's called by [the `oauth2/token` endpoint](https://github.com/ory/hydra/blob/master/oauth2/handler.go#L578)

PS: [These lines look like](https://github.com/ory/hydra/blob/master/persistence/sql/persister_oauth2.go#L345-L351) what would be called when saving and retrieving the PKCE session.  However I don't see them executed anywhere in the package so I don't know how/where the PKCE inputs get validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line creates the PKCE session (adds entry to the table):
https://github.com/ory/fosite/blob/master/handler/pkce/handler.go#L129

Turns out my code was not calling it because PKCE was not listed amongst the `AuthorizeEndpointHandlers` for the `Registry.OAuthProvider()` settings